# How to add trait bound to a non-generic type?

Tags: generics, rust, numbers, polymorphism, traits

I have this simple generic function:

```rust
fn add_five<T: Into<i32>>(t: T) -> i32 {
    5_i32 + t.into()
}
```

Which I would like to express using the `From` trait instead of the `Into` trait, however my attempted refactor:

```rust
fn add_five<T, i32: From<T>>(t: T) -> i32 {
    5_i32 + <i32 as From<T>>::from(t)
}
```

Throws this compile error:

```
error[E0277]: cannot add `i32` to `i32`
  --> src/main.rs:24:11
   |
   |     5_i32 + <i32 as From<T>>::from(t)
   |           ^ no implementation for `i32 + i32`
   |
   = help: the trait `Add<i32>` is not implemented for `i32`
```

Which is very confusing, because there is indeed an [`impl Add<i32> for i32`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i32.html#impl-Add%3Ci32%3E-1) in the standard library, so what's the real problem?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Adding a trait bound to a non-generic type can only be done from the where clause:

```rust
fn add_five<T>(t: T) -> i32
where
    i32: From<T> // now compiles!
{
    5_i32 + <i32 as From<T>>::from(t)
}
```

---

The reason `<T, i32: From<T>>` fails is because the compiler parses all of the names used within `<>` as identifiers for generic type parameters.

The error message is confusing because the compiler doesn't clarify when `i32` refers to the concrete 32-bit signed integer type vs the function-local identifier for a generic type parameter by the same name (which also now shadows the concrete integer type).

Here's the error message but with added clarifications:

```
error[E0277]: cannot add `i32` (generic type) to `i32` (concrete integer type)
  --> src/main.rs:24:11
   |
   |     5_i32 + <i32 (generic type) as From<T>>::from(t)
   |           ^ no implementation for `i32 (concrete integer type) + i32 (generic type)`
   |
   = help: the trait `Add<i32 (generic type)>` is not implemented for `i32` (concrete integer type)
```

Or to substitute the confusingly ambiguous `i32` for the more conventional `U` as the generic type:

```
error[E0277]: cannot add `U` to `i32`
  --> src/main.rs:24:11
   |
   |     5_i32 + <U as From<T>>::from(t)
   |           ^ no implementation for `i32 + U`
   |
   = help: the trait `Add<U>` is not implemented for `i32`
```

The fix is to simply move the bound into the where clause, as stated above, to avoid accidentally declaring `i32` as a generic type.